# Unexpected end-of-file found error in C programming

Tags: c

Hi guys i have been check for my code many many times but i still confuse where is this error come from....
This error appear while build solution...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

 int add(int a, int b);

 int main()
{
int num1, num2, ans;
printf("Please Enter the two numbers :%d %d", num1, num2);

scanf_s("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

ans = add(num1, num2);

return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
int sum = a + b;
printf("\nSummition is = %d", sum);
}
```

Unexpected end-of-file found error

Comment: You'll have to be more specific... did that error message pop up while you were having a coffee or what?

Comment: The code you pasted has non-printable characters at the end, `0x7D 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`, if you are getting a compilation error then perhaps that is the problem

Comment: Also using uninitialized variables. and `add` doesn't return value.

Comment: this error appear while build solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int main() {
   int num1, num2, ans;

   printf("Enter the two numbers : ");
   scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

   ans= sum(num1, num2);

   printf("\nAddition of two number is : ");
   return (0);
}

int sum(int num1, int num2) {
   int num3;
   num3 = num1 + num2;
   return (num3);
}
```

Comment: Hi , after i edit it still appear the same error..

Comment: make void main() instead of int main()

Comment: replace your code with the code i just pisted